# Invalid Header Signature

Tags: java, apache-poi

Here I want to extract the data from `.xlsx` file and for that I already add the poi jar and created the reference of `fileInputStream`

```
package demo;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class DemoExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File excel = new File("C:\\Users\\Devaditya\\Documents\\Book1.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        System.out.println(fis.toString());
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        System.out.println(wb.toString());
        HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Data");
        System.out.println(sh.toString());
    }

}
```

Here i am getting the error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0, expected -2226271756974174256
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlockReader.<init>(HeaderBlockReader.java:88)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:83)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:210)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:191)
    at demo.DemoExcel.main(DemoExcel.java:23)
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696836/excel-read-error-invalid-header-signature-how-to-resolve), your question may be closed.

Answer (score 5):

Lets start with types of [`WorkBook`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html).

**[`HSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html)**

This is old binary proprietary Excel format, know by the extension `.xls`.

**[`XSSFWorkbook`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html)**

This is the new XML Excel format, known by the extension `.xlsx`.

**So, you are using the wrong class.**

In fact it would be better not to use a specific class at all, let POI work out what you have. Use a [`WorkbookFactory`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html):

```
final Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(excel);
```

This is:

1. [programming to the `interface`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384067/2071828).
2. robust to changes in the type of workbook read, as long a POI supports it
3. faster and more efficient. POI can read the `File` piecemeal, when it needs to rather than having to slurp the whole workbook into memory.
4. Doesn't have the memory leak that you have when you don't `close()` the `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Just in case anyone did as me, I'll add that WorkbookFactory is not in poi library, but in poi-ooxml. I spent an hour figuring that one out.

Answer (score 0):

try to open the file in microsoft office Excel then a pop message will appear to inform you that that file you are trying to open isn't an excel file, and give you the choice to open it any way, so just open it and save it as excel file.